# How to run `AWS CLI` command within `aws lambda` function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to run [`aws cli`](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command (actually [`aws s3 sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)) from within the `aws lambda function`. How do I do that? Ideally in `python`, but `javascript` (or `java`) would work too.

Using `python` I tried achieving this by [`Creating a Deployment Package`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) where i would have [`awscli`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awscli) as a python package, so that I can use it later.
However, the `aws` command is not available during lambda function execution, and only the `awscli` package is.

How can I:

- either: make sure that I have `awscli` available to be called during lambda function execution?
- or: construct a `aws s3 sync` call directly from python `awscli` library?

Comment: Why would you want to invoke aws cli from lambda? Can't you get the same using the sdk.

Comment: I do not think so (or at least, i did not find a way to do that). I could, of course, use SDK to create my own `sync` routine, but I really would like to use the one which is already offered by `aws cli` (which internally uses SDK (`botocore`)), but extends it quite a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call aws-cli from AWS Lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513604/call-aws-cli-from-aws-lambda)

Answer (score 1):

Look the project https://github.com/lucioveloso/cli2cloudformation and you will figure out how to wrapper the cli inside a lambda function.

Comment: Put the information in your answer as links can go dead.

Comment: This is actually one of the cleanest solutions I've seen

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking on @lucio-veloso's answer, that's a pretty clever way of invoking the CLI from Python.

Include the `awscli` in your bundle but shipping the `awscli` as a dependency using whatever your build process is.

Then you can run something like:

```
aws_cli_driver = awscli.clidriver.create_clidriver()
aws_cli_driver.main(["s3", "sync", "--delete", "s3://test-my-bucket", "/tmp/my-path"])
if exit_code > 0:
    raise RuntimeError(f"awscli exited: {exit_code}")
```

Which seems to work for my `aws s3 sync` use case for using the AWS CLI in Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

-Install AWS CLI in a local virtual environment

-Package AWS CLI and all its dependencies to a zip file

-Create a Lambda Layer

-Use that layer in your lambda function

Step by step guide is at : 
https://bezdelev.com/hacking/aws-cli-inside-lambda-layer-aws-s3-sync/

Or

use bash layers as suggested in other stack overflow ans 
 [Call aws-cli from AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513604/call-aws-cli-from-aws-lambda)