# AWS DataPipeline insert status with SQLActivity

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-data-pipeline

I am looking for a way to record the status of the pipeline in a DB table. Assuming this is a very common use case.
Is there any way where I can record

1. status and time of completion of the complete pipeline.
2. status and time of completion of selected individual activities.
3. the ID of individual runs/execution.

The only way I found was using SQLActivity that is dependent on an individual activity but even there I cannot access the status or timestamp of the parent/node.

I am using a jdbc connection to connect to a remote SQLServer. And the pipeline is for coping S3 files into the SQLServer DB.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I haven't tried this but I can hit you with some pointers to possibly achieve the desired results. However, you will have to do research & figure out actual implementation.

## Option 1

- Create a ShellCommandActivity, which has `depends on` set to last activity in your pipeline. Your shell will use aws-cli to [`list-runs`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/datapipeline/list-runs.html) details of the current run, you can use filters to achieve this.
- Use [Staging Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-concepts-staging.html) to move output of previous ShellActivity to SQLActivity to eventually insert into the destination SQLServer.

## Option 2

- Use AWS lambda to run aws-cli data-pipeline `list-runs` periodically, with filters, & update the destination table with latest activities. [Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382837/how-to-run-aws-cli-command-within-aws-lambda-function)