# launch child process in aws lambda environment

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using this code to launch chromium child process on my desktop machine:

```
    import childProcess from "child_process";
    import chromium from "@sparticuz/chromium";

    childProcess.spawn(
        await chromium.executablePath(), // resolves to /tmp/chromium
        ["--remote-debugging-port=61000"],
        {
            detached: true,
        }
    );
   
    async connect(headless){
        let repeat = true;
        while(repeat) {
            repeat = false;
            if(headless){
                var r = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:61000/json/new?about:blank", {method:"PUT"}).then(d => d.json()).catch((e) => {repeat = true;console.log(e);});
            }else{
                var r = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:61000/json/version").then(d => d.json()).catch((e) => {repeat = true;console.log(e);});
            }
            await WaitForTimeout(100)
        }
}


// connect to chromium
await connect(true);
```

While it works as expected on a desktop machine, it fails to run in AWS lambda environment. The error I get is `FetchError: request to http://127.0.0.1:61000/json/new?about:blank failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:61000` signaling that either child process was not started or less likely the port does 61000 is not enabled for listening.

How does one start a child process in aws lambda environment?

Comment: AWS Lambda functions don't support inbound connections. I suspect this extends to the runtime environment and might prevent localhost-style connections too.

Comment: Any idea on how to debug the problem more precisely? I wanted to inspect the running processes with `ps-list` npm package, but package does not work in aws with an error spawn ps ENOENT

Comment: You can test whether or not spawning a child process works in general by [spawning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223979/capturing-output-from-process-spawned-from-nodejs-lambda) well-known, available software such as `ps axu` or `python -v` and capturing and logging the output.